# Adding a Tkinter button to matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

The internet is full of information on how to embed a matplotlib figure into a Tkinter screen or widget.

I'm trying to accomplish the opposite. Given an existing matplotlib figure, I want to add a button somewhere within the figure. (Specifically, I want the button to copy the contents of the figure to clipboard, but I've already got code that does that part.)

E.g. something along the lines of:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import Tkinter as tk

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot([1,2,3], [11,13,12])
button = tk.Button(fig, text="copy", command=lambda: copy_to_clipboard(fig))
button.pack(*location_details)
```

But of course a matplotlib figure is not a good master for Tkinter widgets, so this code isn't going to work at all.

Comment: what about adding both widgets (fig and button) to the same master and arranging them using `place()` on top of each other?

Comment: @Raphael, I considered that possibility, and I may do that if this turns out to be impossible, but it's definitely not my preferred solution. I have a function which manipulates all open figures, and I'd have to re-write that function almost entirely.

Comment: what for would you need to rewrite the manipulation routine? the references for the figures will stay the same. The problem I see atm at your setup is: you do not want to add the button to the figure so you need either same master for both or implement a way into the figure to have buttons. Second way would be: bindings to the figure or a context menu instead of a button. is that an option?